# TinyMCE 4 Angular 2 - How to make a toggle button to hide/show toolbar

Tags: angular, tinymce-4

I use TinyMCE 4 editor for Angular 2, now I want make a button for toggle hide/show some buttons on toolbar of editor, how do I do?

Answer (score 0):

The code for change toolbar after init is

```
tinymce.EditorManager.settings.toolbar = yourToolbar;
```

After that you must remove and then add your editor for apply change:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, "editorId");
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, "editorId");
```